# How to control Matrice600pro landing gear with osdk?

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to control Matrice600 pro landing gear using osdk.

I tried like below:

vehicle->control->action(Control::FlightCommand::landingGearUp,10);

and

vehicle->control->action(Control::FlightCommand::landingGearDown,10);

but this is no effect.

I have changed DJI GO's landing gear setting and could control by RC.

Does someone have any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

you need to test this in the real word.Maybe you try this function: vehicle->control->action(29.0.0).

Comment: I tried but it was no effect. I checked DJI GO's settings too.